# put delete button in kendo grid js

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, kendo-grid

hi i try to put delete button in each rows of Kendo grid. my datasource is a list and My function does not contain column part. so What should I do?

in controller:

```
List<DataRow> lstCompany = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().ToList();
ViewBag.lstCompany = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds.Tables[0], Formatting.Indented);
```

in view:

```
$(function () {
    var people = @Html.Raw(ViewBag.lstCompany);
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            data: people },

    });

})
```

Comment: welcome @mhg, you are not mention kendo jquery or asp.net version. please see the answer its commonly in both type of controls

Answer (score 0):

Kendo gives inbuild functionality for the edit/delete button or you can use custom template too.

While defining grid's column, add command column like

```
{ command: ["edit", {
                name: "myDelete",
                text: "Delete"
              }]
```

See this links : [Display Delete Confirmation as Button in the Command Column](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/how-to/Editing/display-delete-confirmation-buttons-command-column)

https://www.telerik.com/forums/grid-edit-delete-update-buttons-template